# Save a List of custom object in savedInstanceState

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am currently building an app to retrieve information for a remote server. the data received are JSON and I am build a list of Data using the class below :

```
public class RedditData {

    private RedditTopic data;

    public RedditTopic getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

and RedditTopic class is defined as below:

```
public final class RedditTopic {
    private static final String TAG = RedditTopic.class.getSimpleName();

    private String author;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String title;
    private String num_comments;
    private long created_utc;
    private String data;
    private String name;

    public RedditTopic(){};

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getThumbnail(){
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getComments(){
        return num_comments + " comments";
    }

    public long getCreated_utc(){
        return created_utc;
    }

    public String getRedditName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

both of these classes are used to translate a JSON into an Object formatted data.

I do not want to really change them to make them Parceable to avoid impacting the extraction of JSON.

I have added :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SAVE");
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("RedditList", myListOfData );
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> RESTORE");
    List<RedditData> myListOfData = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("RedditList");
}
```

Android complain because I need to implement Parceable in my class RedditData and I assume probably in the RedditTopic Class as well because RedditData returned a List of RedditTopic.

Is there a better way to do it? keep the List as I have it without requiring the Parceable option.

I do not have a List of String, it's a list of object.

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: Why are you so hesitant to just make them `Parcelable`? It's the correct way to do it and it won't mess with the extraction of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make your model objects parcleable.

There is a great extension, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator that will generate the neccesary parcelable methods for your class.

I highly recommend it.